# Magento compiler broken. Compiler doesnt work even via SSH

Tags: error, compiler

I deleted the `includes/src` folder to disable the compiler mode.

Then the site broke and all we can see is the following.

> Warning: include_once(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/Mage.php on
>   line 51
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for
>   inclusion
>   (include_path='/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/local:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/community:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/core:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 51
>
> Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on
>   line 68
>
> Warning: include(Varien/Autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in
>   /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on
>   line 68
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Varien/Autoload.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/local:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/community:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/core:/home2/hotelhome/public_html/lib:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php')
>   in /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php
>   on line 68
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in
>   /home2/hotelhome/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 54

When we tried to run the compiler from the shell, the same errors. Uncommenting the include path in the `config.php` file does not work either.

Can not log into admin. Same errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow the folder     lib/varien was not present. Copied it from a fresh Magento installation and everything worked.